# Bootstrap CSS not found while hosting in pythonanywhere

Tags: python, css, flask, bootstrap-4, flask-admin

I am trying to make an admin panel that includes some database. I have used flask-admin to automatically generate admin panel. When I ran the server locally in my PC, the bootstrap swatch is loading and works fine. However, when I hosted it in `pythonanywhere` and ran, it shows that the CSS is not found as shown in the image.

I have not used any templates of my own for admin panel. I used the following code to automatically generate the template.

```
admin = Admin(app, name='Admin Panel', template_mode='bootstrap3')
```

Link for the error message.

[image]

Comment: Have you looked on the [pythonanywhere forums](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/forums/)? It seems like you need help from people who are experts on this platform.

Comment: ok i will look into the forums.

Answer (score 1):

Same happened to me, but it turned out I used an unsupported swatch, here is the code that worked

```
app.config['FLASK_ADMIN_SWATCH'] = 'flatly'

# Create admin with custom base template
admin = admin.Admin(app, name='XXX', template_mode='bootstrap4')
```

Note that the Bootswatch theme name is **case-sensitive**. If set the `FLASK_ADMIN_SWATCH` config is set properly, there is no need to add the flask-admin css and js files to the `static` folder of your project.

The available themes are on the [repo](https://github.com/flask-admin/flask-admin/tree/master/flask_admin/static/bootstrap/bootstrap4/swatch).